# Invalid JPEG data, size 43 error in building part of retraining inceptionv3 of tensorflow for poets

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, image-recognition

I am trying to train my model of image recognition using tensorflow for poets .
It is getting build for the example case of flower data and generates bottle necks too but when i try to retrain it for another test case (where i made four folders namely Chandler,Darth,Ross,Joey in a folder named tf_files this folder is present in my home)

when i run this command

```
python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \
--bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/bottlenecks \
--how_many_training_steps 500 \
--model_dir=/tf_files/inception \
--output_graph=/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
--output_labels=/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
--image_dir /tf_files
```

I am getting this error

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Invalid JPEG data, size 
43[[Node: DecodeJpeg = DecodeJpeg[acceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, 
dct_method="", fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, 
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_DecodeJpeg
/contents_0)]]
```

and many warning

But when i run the above command just for flower standard example

```
python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \
--bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/bottlenecks \
--how_many_training_steps 500 \
--model_dir=/tf_files/inception \
--output_graph=/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
--output_labels=/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
--image_dir /flower_photos
```

I am not getting any error .My model gets retrained and i get a prediction

Being very new in this field please guide where i am wrong be its installation mistake or something

Answer (score 0):

The error that you get is because there might be a few images in your dataset that are of `png` format. On the other hand, the flower dataset has all images of `jpeg` format.

Also, the `retrain.py` is written to handle images of `jpeg` format. You might want to follow [this thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4009) to know more about handling `png` images